# Are questions about self-learning on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about self-learning on-topic?

They are on-topic on Mathematics Educators to some extend. Maybe the two discussions on their meta site might be of use. I also found a discussion on Area 51:

- https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25291/
- https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/
  https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I love [Jim Belk's](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/78) answer.  Here's my reworking of his answer for our needs:

Questions about computer science itself would almost always be better answered on [CS Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

However, regarding questions that are more about pedagogy, they would be welcomed here. Jim says, "as a self learner, part of your job is to design a curriculum for yourself, and curriculum questions are certainly on topic here. It would also be on-topic to ask questions about pedagogical choices made by textbook, i.e. why are things presented in a certain order, or why are certain topics included."

So, some potential questions that would be appropriate for us might include:

1. Here is the learning plan I've made for ___.  Is this a good approach?
2. Does it make sense to learn pointer manipulation before arrays?
3. Why do books on programming languages discuss type checking prior to formal semantics?
4. Why does my textbook deal so much with $\lambda$-Calculus? Do I really need this topic?
5. What programming concepts should I review before taking a course on database design?