# A student on the educators site

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I'm a student, and I'd like to ask a question of CS educators - where I can take online courses that are on the cheaper side of things and will (probably) be able to go on my transcript. This leads to a two-part question:

1. Is this question on topic?
2. Are questions *like this one* (i.e., from a student to an educator) on-topic?

Thanks!

Comment: Heather, I welcome you, but I didn't realize you were in 8th grade until you mentioned it in a question. I guess if we will get many underage students here, I will watch my metaphors. I hope that you find this site as useful as I have!

Comment: Related: https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/are-questions-about-self-learning-on-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My instinct is that the meta discussion that Aurora pointed to is spot-on.  As long as the comment is about the *“process of teaching or learning <sub><strike>mathematics</strike></sub> computer science”* (with the key word there being **process**), then I believe that such a question would be welcomed by the community here.  Truthfully, as a teacher, I could certainly learn from such a discussion, even if the answers are oriented towards the self-learner.

As far as a question specifically about course recommendations for credit, that might be pushing the boundaries of acceptable here.  It is not really related to the process of teaching, even if I squint my eyes when I look at it and screw my head sideways.  It's really fundamentally about something else.

If you want to make sure that the course could offer college credit, then I would look to Academia.SE.  For high school credit, ask around in your high school's guidance office.

Comment: I'm not sure if Academia would accept it—they specifically say "Undergraduate-specific issues that could not apply to graduate or post-graduate academicians" are off-topic, but I'm not familiar enough with their scope to know if this question would fall under that. It would be worth @heather asking in their chat, perhaps, to see if it's relevant over there.

Comment: Yeah, Academia is really more about the graduate level than college in general. In particular, professors, PhD candidates... people who are doing research and publishing in peer-reviewed journals. The SE network doesn't currently have a good place for just college course questions.

Answer (score 5):

Questions about designing a curriculum or finding learning resources for yourself are likely on-topic here. There haven't been many questions to test whether they're well-received yet, but there is a [self-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) tag on the site, with 3 questions as of writing.

Without more details, I would guess that *yes*, your question would fit here. Feel free to edit your question with an example of what you'd be planning to post, but here's how I see it:

- Asking *how* to teach yourself a subject (curriculum design, resources to use, etc.) **is** a part of education, hence on topic here.
- If you're looking for a specific course to follow, you'll need to be careful to set out some objective criteria to avoid being *too broad* or *primarily opinion-based*. If you specify as much as you can (language you want to use, ideas you want to cover), then your question will probably be answerable, but without constraints, I fear there might be too many options to reasonably answer.

Mathematics Educators [also has a [self-learning] tag](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning), and the discussion on whether self-learners are involved in education [has already been covered](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/self-learner-considerations/). I feel it would be exceptionally confusing and counterproductive to argue that self-learning isn't covered here, if the questions could cover nearly the exact same ground as a question posed from the perspective of an educator teaching a class.

[Designing an AI curriculum](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/66/2) for a course isn't particularly different to designing a curriculum **for yourself**, and draws from the same pool of expertise, so calling these questions off-topic when they aren't really problematic *in any way* is harmful to the site.

Good luck, and feel free to visit [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/computer-science-educators) if you want to discuss anything that doesn't fit into Q&A, or if you want to run a question idea by other users before you post it.

Comment: Thanks! So overall, it's okay to have questions from a student on here?

Comment: @heather I personally think so, yes. As long as your question would be relevant to people involved with teaching CS (either to themselves or others), it would probably be on-topic here. I suggest you try asking the question and see; there isn't really any precedent yet, and I'd be interested to see how the community responds.

Answer (score -2):

> **CS Educators** — Q&A site for those involved in the field of teaching Computer Science.

That seems pretty explicit. This site was set up *specifically* for teachers, not students. We have a lot of sites about how to learn programming, but this one was specifically targeted at educators to discuss the challenges and teaching methodologies in this subject space. I don't think it is a good idea to intentionally overlap into the scope of all our learner-centric sites in this manner.

Comment: My question is about teaching, just about teaching oneself.

Comment: @heather Are you giving the course? or are you a student?

Comment: I am both the teacher and the student, that's the nature of self-teaching.

Comment: @heather then I guess that's what the whole network is about.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that to be honest. This is a site about teaching computer science. I'm asking for a resource to help me teach computer science. The only caveat is that I'm teaching myself. You're coming across as very testy about this, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I do agree that this site is (and should) be *oriented* towards educators who are teachers. And yet, the process of self-learning gives insight about teaching. As such, reflecting this insight and perspective in questions and answers on the site is quite beneficial for teachers, as well as other self learners. Answers on how to teach one's self are applicable for teaching a class (with a few adaptions and changes, but the core answer is applicable). Overall, this site can permit self-learners who ask good questions (just like any teacher, in most cases).

Comment: Maybe I should have written that as an answer. Do you think there's value to putting it as an answer?

Comment: I am going to have to agree with @RobertCartaino on this one. Self teaching is great but until that person teaches another person (with no regard to the actual age of the teacher) I don't think they would become teachers.